# Hosted application : File permissions , passing arguments from javascript to application

Tags: javascript, web-services, hosted-app

I am very new to  web hosted application area. 
I have an exe application. It is a windows console application. It takes some arguments( number and strings) and output some (numbers and string) . I want to make it web hosted.
For simplicity  we will consider following case. The exe is add.exe and takes two integer as input. It returns their sum. I want to  make add.exe web hosted. I do not want “add.exe” to be readable( downloadable) by the site visitor. I have javascript   that will take two numbers as input and and display the output ( obtained from add.exe ) . 
Questions: 
On the http server what should be the permission of the directory that has javascript file.
What should be the permission of the javascript file.
How do I pass arguments to 
What should be relative path of add.exe ( with respect to the javascript files) and permissions of the add.exe, permission of directories appearing in the relative path?
Environment: 
Please assume linux hosted. Do not worry about use of “exe” in the question. It can be any executable( and is not specific to windows). You may assume a C++ linux compiled executable( of that is needed for your answer, else please try to keep answer generic)

Comment: First Google. Try it yourself and when you are stuck then ask your problem here.

Comment: I tried googling beforeasking this question. Nothing on file permission. Some soltuion were asp.net related.  Please mention any link you think is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware, the .exe will not get executed on the browser. you will need a HTML page to get the values and use C++ in the backend. The .exe file will always get downloaded irrespective of the file permissions. So the basic logic of executing a exe file on the browser is wrong.

Comment: I agree. I intend to run the exe on the server.